# Dual boot Ubuntu - Mac Os Issue

Tags: dual-boot, mac

I installed Ubuntu in dual boot on my mac without using rEFInd. Initially everything worked fine, I could access both systems. Later, in an attempt to remove Ubuntu, I deleted a partition I had created for swap and since then grub has replaced the mac's boot loader. So now I can only access Ubuntu. I would like to be able to access mac os again without losing any data. How can I do that ? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a question about the macOS bootloader, so I doubt we will be able to help you here. I suggest deleting this post and asking instead on [apple.se] where the mac folks hang out.

Comment: Just in case anyone else encounters this issue, here is the solution. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430590/dual-boot-ubuntu-macos-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can now install refind from within ubuntu https://rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html . This should allow you to boot to your MacOS installation